# How do I find recipe_dag_template.html?

Tags: databricks, mlflow, mlrecipes

My Recipe was successfully created, but when I went to inspect it, I received an error:

`TemplateNotFound: resources/recipe_dag_template.html`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is a bug being worked out. Until then, DBR 12.2 LTS ML with the following requirements.txt works.